# How do I run an init script in a docker container that was created by committing a mysql5.7 container with an existing database?

Tags: mysql, docker

I have a big static database where no data is inserted / updated.

I created a Dockerfile in the following manner which works well to create the database in the docker container. There are a bunch of insert .sql scripts in data/ which populates the database.

```sh
FROM mysql:5.7
ADD data/* /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
EXPOSE 3306
```

The only problem with this is that it takes a long time to start up, so I ran the container locally and adjusted it slightly so that the data persisted within the container, and I removed the startup scripts from the startup script directory. I then committed this container to a new docker image (`committed-image:v1`).

This worked, however the only problem I have is that the password for the mysql root user for this database is fixed to the password which I used when I committed the image.

My question is: Is there any way to run another startup script on top of this new image (which already has an existing database)? I need to modify the password of the root user to match an environment variable in the container (cant use `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD` now since the startup script no longer runs in the container spun up from the new committed image).

Answer (score 1):

The trouble is your [entrypoint](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/master/5.7/docker-entrypoint.sh) script for mysql:5.7 (the default) is quite elaborate. DATABASE_ALREADY_EXISTS is based on the existence of the mysql/database directory and therefore the ROOT doesn't get reinitialized. Its hard to get a loaded database to exist without a system tables include a root user being set.

Solutions:

a) the default configuration of mysql instance isn't particularly conducive to large database loads. Including a configuration item that sets innodb_buffer_pool_size to several gig of ram/80% of available RAM will help the load and run.

and/or:

b) set [innodb_file_per_table=1](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_file_per_table) in the configuration and then for your SQL, use [CREATE TABLESPACE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-tablespace.html) / `ALTER TABLE .. TABLESPACE =` to load the data from a pre-geneated idb file. See [these instructions from the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-table-import.html#innodb-table-import-partitions)  on extracting a tablespace.

To create/set configuration file settings see the readme notes from [dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/). You could also just drop in a file like `/etc/mysql/conf.d/config-file.cnf` in your Dockerfile.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. looks like it's better to optimize the load rather than creating the new image as I have done.

Comment: Depends how big is "big". There's a few other settings in [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/83125/mysql-any-way-to-import-a-huge-32-gb-sql-dump-faster/83385#83385) that also apply to containers `set global innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1` at the end of your SQL. Also considers 'LOAD DATA INFILE', and as a second preference, that your insert statements contain multiple values (i.e. like from `mysqldump --extended-insert`).